# Tower of Hanoi [Edit] - k peg solution

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, binary-tree, towers-of-hanoi

I was able to come up with an algorithm (logical) to solve a k-peg solution for the Tower of Hanoi problem, but when I implement my code, I was getting segmentation fault.

```
void move(int number_of_disks, int source, int dest, vector <int> free_peg, int pointer)
    {
        int p;

        if (1 == number_of_disks)
        {
            moves++;
            move_top_disk (source, dest);
        }

        if(free_peg.size() > 2)
            p = number_of_disks/2;
        else 
            p = number_of_disks - 1;

        moves++;
        //Move top "p" disks from peg 1 to peg i
        move(p, source, free_peg.back(),free_peg, pointer); 
        //Move "n - p - 1" disks from peg 1 to another peg 
        move(number_of_disks - p - 1, source, free_peg[pointer--], free_peg, pointer++);
        //Move the "last disk" from the source peg to the destination
        move_top_disk(source, dest);
        //Move "n - p - 1" disks from peg (i - 1) to the final peg
        move(number_of_disks - p - 1, free_peg[pointer--], dest, free_peg, pointer++);
        //Move "p" disks from peg i to the destination
        move(p, free_peg.back(), dest, free_peg, pointer);
    }
```

The idea is pretty simple, I keep a vector of free pegs (or towers) and I update that when I move my disks throughout. So for the case of 6 pegs and n disks, I have one source, one destination and 4 free pegs. The idea is to move (n - p) where p ~ n/2 from the source to free_peg[3] (the fourth free peg). Now I only have 3 free pegs in my vector, I use those 3 free pegs to move (n - p - 1) disks to free_peg[2] and then I move the last disk from the source to the destination. So now I have 2 free pegs and 1 source = 3 free pegs. Next, I need to move (n - p - 1) disks from peg[2] to the destination using 3 free pegs (including the source which is now free). Finally, move p disks from free_peg[3] to the destination using 4 free pegs. However, when I implement this in my code, I am getting a segmentation fault, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `move(number_of_disks - p - 1, source, free_peg[pointer--], free_peg, pointer++);` is undefined behaviour, you're modifying `pointer` twice without intervening sequence point. So it's impossible to be sure what happens without analysing your compiler. But I guess you're trying to access `free_peg` out of bounds.

Comment: +1 @DanielFischer, parameter evaluation order prior to pass is undefined in the language. the only guarantee you have is that *all* of them will be evaluated prior to the actual call.

Comment: So I can't change the values of "pointer" in the function call?

Comment: Not with using `pointer` more than once in the argument list. Use temporary variables or expressions that don't modify `pointer`. If you thought argument evaluation was left-to right, `move(...,...,free_peg[pointer],...,pointer-1);` would do what you intended.

Comment: I get the same segmentation fault, I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my logic. Is there anything you can see wrong here?

Comment: The only output I get is: "Move disk 1 from Peg1 to Peg3" and then a segmentation fault.

Comment: Was it your intention to pass your std::vector<int> by value? (i.e. copy construction at each call?)

Comment: Yes, because the vector keeps track of all the free pegs I would need to move around the disks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve a k-peg general solution, thanks for the help. Here is how the algorithm goes:

```
void move(int number_of_disks, int source, int dest, vector <int> free_peg)
    {
        int p, middle, g;

        if (1 == number_of_disks)
        {
            moves++;
            move_top_disk (source, dest);
        }

        else
        {
            moves++;

            if(free_peg.size() >= 2)
                p = number_of_disks/2;
            else
                p = number_of_disks - 1;

            //Move top "p" disks from peg 1 to peg i
            middle = free_peg.back();
            free_peg.pop_back();
            free_peg.push_back(dest);
            move(p, source, middle,free_peg);

            //Move "n - p " disks from peg 1 to another peg
            free_peg.pop_back();
            move(number_of_disks - p, source, dest, free_peg);

                    //Move p from current peg to the final peg
            free_peg.push_back(source);
            move(p, middle, dest, free_peg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I took a leave of absence there, Josh. I just started thinking about this again when you got back on, even coding it as well. Very nice solution, btw. A pretty-clean impl of Frame-Stewart. grats!